# How to control the space between categories in a barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have done a barplot in RStudio successfully, but I want to decrease the space between the categories (CPLEX and Heurística), but I can't do it. My objective is to make this figures thinner since I am working in a latex file where I want to put two of this plots side by side in the same line, but they are too wide and the get out of the margins. My code is the following.

```
library("ggplot2")

df <- data.frame(
  Metodo = factor(c("CPLEX","Heurística"),levels=c("CPLEX","Heurística")),
  Item = factor(c("Demanda total","UE","UI")),
  Unidades = c(6440,6291,0,6440,6440,149)
)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Metodo, y=Unidades, fill=Item)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black",width=0.3) + 
  theme(text = element_text(family="serif", size=12,face="bold")) + 
  labs(x = "Método") + 
  ggtitle("Instancia 1") + 
  theme(legend.position="top")
ggsave("I1.png")
```

And the output is

[image]

I would like to reduce the wide of this plot, obviously without deforming it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `width` into `position_dodge`:

```r
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Metodo, y=Unidades, fill=Item)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width = 0.5), colour="black",width=0.3) +
  theme(text=element_text(family="serif", size=12,face="bold"))+labs(x="Método")+ggtitle("Instancia 1")+theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]